# Calculate CSS value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jInvertscroll.

I am using this horizontal scroller script and it is giving me headache's atm.
I need to position elements with

```
left: xxxx px
```

I am reading information out of my database and this creates divs for me, so creating classes from 1 to infinty, giving each class +500px on the 'left' property would be dumb.

I thought about this solution: 
If i made inline style with a small javascript calculation

```
Left = 500px + 500px + 500px + 500px + 500px
for     div1    div2    div3    div4    div5
```

Which would become `<div style="left:500px;">`

Do you guys think this will work, if yes. Could someone provide me with a script(I am terrible at javascript).

Greetings, Chris.

Comment: Why not just use `float: left`?

Comment: @DonovanM Because you have to use position:fixed

Comment: Then why use position fixed? Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, as I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Ah, I just took a look at their site. Looks like just the scrolling div "layers" need to use `position: fixed`. I used the inspector on that page and set the "pages" inside the scrolling div to `float: left` and everything still works.

Comment: @DonovanM That is because they receive left properties and values from CSS styling.

Comment: The divs with the class `page` do have left values but they also have `position: absolute` instead of fixed. If you remove the `position: absolute` and replace it with `float: left` everything still displays fine (you'll probably want to add a margin to the left and right, however). The container div is what needs to be `position: fixed`.

Comment: @DonovanM Thank you, it worked. But now I have another issue; I need to get the total width of those children divs, and assign that outcome to the parent div. Any idea how..?

Comment: As long as they are the same width you can just take the number of divs and multiply that by the width + margin.

Comment: @DonovanM I have 0 experience with javascript. Also I cannot find something easily. Can you help me?